# Create API to pass integer value from spring boot to angular and View in web page

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm developing an application which stores data in mongoDB and the data is passed to the angular frontend using spring rest api. In that process I need to pass an integer value to the frontend but integers can not be directly sent and as far as I know I have to use ResponseEntity but I my knowledge regarding that is low, so please help me.

After the answers I changed my api as below,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {
   @Autowired
   Repository repository;

   private ArrayList<Member> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

   @GetMapping("/members")
   public List<Member> getAll(){
      return repository.findAll();
   }

   @GetMapping("/members/all")
   public ResponseEntity<Integer> findCount(){
      arrayList.addAll(repository.findAll());
      return new ResponseEntity<>(arrayList.size(),HttpStatus.OK);
   }

}
```

So after this api created how to get show it in the web page?

**service.ts**

```
export class HttpClientService {

constructor(
private httpClient: HttpClient
) { }

private userUrl= 'http://localhost:8080/api/members';

getMembers(){
  return this.httpClient.get<DefaultMember[]>(this.userUrl);
}

getCount(){
  return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/members/all');
}
}
```

**dashboardcomponent.ts**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
private httpClientService: HttpClientService
)    { }

ngOnInit(): void {}

count(){
this.httpClientService.getCount()
}
}
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
    <div class="huge">****members****</div>
    <div class="phrase">Total Members</div>
</div>
```

I want to get the value inside div class huge. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

A common practice is to return an object with the field(s) that you need.

This way, if in the future you like to add more fields, it is relatively easy.

So something like:

```
@Getters / Setters /...
class MyResponse{
    int count;
}
```

And also, if you are using `Repository`  there should be `count()` method in there, so you don't need to `findAll` and count it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your API to pass a Http Status Code you either use the annotation

```
@ResonseStatus(HttpStatus.YOUR_STATUS_CODE)
```

Or use the response entity as shown below:

```java
//With ResponseStatus

    @GetMapping("/members/all")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public int findCount(){
        arrayList.addAll(repository.findAll());
        return arrayList.size();
    }

// With ResponseEntity

    @GetMapping("/members/all")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> findCount(){
        arrayList.addAll(repository.findAll());
        return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(arrayList.size());
    }
```

Still, I would higly recommend you to create a specific Object to receive this number, I've made and example using a mock API and some Angular code, this way you can check it working in real time and see the code in action:

The app working is here on this [link](https://angular-w4xst3.stackblitz.io).

And the source code you can check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w4xst3).

For references you can go [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide.html) to see how the response is buid.

Comment: can you please tell me about how to get that value to show from frontend (angular) (I used response status) ?

Comment: Do you have an example form your Angular code to show us? That would make things a little bit easier.

Comment: As @riorio commented bellow, you can create an object and inside you can have the field. This strategy is used very often.

Comment: I edited the question, if you can please help me with it.

Comment: Nice, I've made some changes on my answer and added some code so you can use as a template for your code.